# Upload photo to facebook group Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to make a post with photos as attachments to my facebook group where I'm admin using user access token. Permissions:

```
user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location, user_likes, user_events, user_photos, user_videos, user_friends, user_status, user_tagged_places, user_posts, user_gender, user_link, user_age_range, email, read_insights, read_audience_network_insights, publish_video, manage_pages, pages_manage_cta, pages_manage_instant_articles, pages_show_list, publish_pages, read_page_mailboxes, ads_management, ads_read, business_management, pages_messaging, pages_messaging_phone_number, pages_messaging_subscriptions, instagram_basic, instagram_manage_comments, instagram_manage_insights, publish_to_groups, groups_access_member_info, leads_retrieval, public_profile, basic_info
```

I tried multi-photo story solution: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads#publishing-a-multi-photo-story

> For each photo in the story, upload it as published=false using the /user-id/photos endpoint.

but with published=false I'm getting error:

```
"message": "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions"
```

With published=true it works as expected (publishing new single photo to group), but I don't need that functionality. I can't even upload to my photos (me/photos endpoint) with published=False, same error.

Answer (score 0):

That solution only works for Pages (and appearently user profiles, according to the docs), because on Pages you can also schedule posts with that parameter. In groups, you can only publish immediately.

Btw, `publish_actions` is deprecated, you should read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to make a post to groups with photos using graph API? I just checked, there are scheduled posts in groups: http://prntscr.com/kc284g

Comment: the bigger question is: why even try, when it stops working in a few days because of the breaking changes?

Comment: btw, my bad, it seems to work for user profiles too, but there is no mention about groups: "You can upload an unpublished photo without publishing a story to the /user-id/photos or /page-id/photos edge"